# How to hide/show JS-generated content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to hide/show javascript-generated content, see below:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $("body").html('<a href="# id="ipsum">Show Ipsum</a><br />' +
        '<p id="lorem_content">Lorem</p><p id="ipsum_content">Ipsum</p>' +
        '<p id="dolor_content">dolor</p>');
    $("p").hide();
    $("p#lorem_content").show();

    $("a").live("click", function() {
        $("p").hide();
        $("p#" + $(this).attr('id') + "_content").show();
    });
});​
```

http://jsbin.com/olebu3/edit

The content, which should shows after clicking on `a#ipsum` is not being shown... why?
The jQuery `hide()` method should just set to the content "`display:none`", not remove the content, isn't that true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `<a href="# id="ipsum"` to `<a href="#" id="ipsum"` in second line. You forgot a quote

Comment: Also, you do not neeed to use 'p#<id>' for jQuery '#<id>' is at least as fast if not faster since document.getElementById is the fastest method to get an element and jQuery uses that one for selectors starting with #.